# How to add a custom product attribute to PDF Invoice Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom, invoice, pdf

Solved this myself, but was a pain so thought I'd share the knowledge,

In `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/DefaultInvoice.php`

in public function draw()

under lines[];

add :

```
$id = $item->getProductid();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
$brand = $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
```

Change `manufacturer` to whatever custom attribute code you want.

Quick and dirty - yes I know its a mod of core code and will translate to my own module now it's working, but hope this makes others life easier.

Answer (score 2):

The above solution failed to show some attribute and this is what worked for me:

Add the following code In

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/DefaultInvoice.php

in public function draw()

```
    $id = $item->getProductid();
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
    $locationCode = $product->getData('location');
```

Then draw the Attribute:

```
        $lines[0][] = [
        'text' => $locationCode,
        'feed' => 290,
        'align' => 'right',
    ];
```

Comment: But this code is not working in magento 2.4.0, any update ?