# Magento 2 : How to edit invoice PDF, Add Product Attributes

Tags: magento2, invoice, invoice-pdf

How to edit the invoice PDF, I want to add more product attributes to the pdf invoice. For example, I have a product which is a book I want to add publisher, author attribute to the invoice.

See Image Below For More Clarification.

[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222897/how-to-add-a-custom-product-attribute-to-pdf-invoice-magento-2

Comment: First modify directly core files and see if its working for you. If its working then create custom module for this modification. If face issues in extension just let me know I will create it for you

Comment: yes, I tried but it's not working like I want.